# windows phone 8 sqlite store beta app performance issues

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone

my app performance is fine in debug version but very slow when i uploaded the release version to the store as beta, i think it might be because of sqlite. i am using `SQLite.WP80, Version=3.8.4.3`  here is my code

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
{
    verses = db.Table<schools>().ToList();
}
```

it seems weird for me as the performance is good in debug version

ps. the application is developed for windows phone 8 but my device ruining 8.1 developer preview

Comment: Did you try using the new version 3.8.5.

Comment: nop, but the problem seems wired as it appeared after uploading to the store as a beta version.
i'll give the new version a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because of the location of the database, at first i just added it to my assets file and access it directly from there, that was okay while i push my to the device using the visual studio
but when i upload it as beta version to the store the performance was very very bad

the solution: 
i added a piece of to copy it to the isolated storage folder first, the application was okay

```
 private void CopyDatabase()
    {

        IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        String DBFile = "CountryDB.sqlite";
        if (!ISF.FileExists(DBFile)) CopyFromContentToStorage(ISF, "Assets/CountryDB.sqlite", DBFile);

    }

    private void CopyFromContentToStorage(IsolatedStorageFile ISF, String SourceFile, String DestinationFile)
    {
        Stream Stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(SourceFile, UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
        IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFS = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(DestinationFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, ISF);
        CopyStream(Stream, ISFS);
        ISFS.Flush();
        ISFS.Close();
        Stream.Close();
        ISFS.Dispose();
    }

    private void CopyStream(Stream Input, IsolatedStorageFileStream Output)
    {
        Byte[] Buffer = new Byte[5120];
        Int32 ReadCount = Input.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
        while (ReadCount > 0)
        {
            Output.Write(Buffer, 0, ReadCount);
            ReadCount = Input.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the async methods for getting data.  It will make the app feel more responsive

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
{
    verses = await db.Table<schools>().ToListAsync();
}
```